# Android MapFragment in a ConstraintLayout fails

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

The template Google Maps project in Android Studio 2.2 fails when the Mapfragment is inside a ConstraintLayout.  Simply changing the ConstraintLayout to 'RelativeLayout' fixes the problem.

The following works fine in activity_main.xml - ie. the google map appears on the phone.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    tools:context="tech.trilobite.geology.MainActivity">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="tech.trilobite.geology.MainActivity"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If 'RelativeLayout' is changed to 'android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout' then I get the same information in the log, but I just get a white screen - no map.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        //SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        //        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
     }


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Build.gradle ..

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tech.trilobite.geology"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
}
```

.. and the ConstraintLayout that does not show the Google Map (just a white screen) ..

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    tools:context="tech.trilobite.geology.MainActivity">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="tech.trilobite.geology.MainActivity"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

.. and the 'Android Monitor' log (this is the same with both RelativeLayout and ConstraintLayout but the former works and the latter doesn't) ..

```
11-26 09:14:24.569 30654-30654/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-26 09:14:24.599 30654-30661/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
11-26 09:14:24.608 30654-30661/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
11-26 09:14:24.608 30654-30661/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
11-26 09:14:24.626 30654-30654/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/tech.trilobite.geology-1/lib/arm64
11-26 09:14:24.639 30654-30654/? I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is tech.trilobite.geology, real application class is null.
11-26 09:14:26.222 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/tech.trilobite.geology-1/lib/arm64
11-26 09:14:26.267 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
11-26 09:14:26.432 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology I/zzai: Making Creator dynamically
11-26 09:14:26.558 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: 
11-26 09:14:26.651 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000018/n/arm64-v8a
11-26 09:14:26.706 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
11-26 09:14:26.721 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 10084000
11-26 09:14:26.735 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 10084440
11-26 09:14:26.758 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
11-26 09:14:26.784 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
11-26 09:14:26.799 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
11-26 09:14:26.811 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
11-26 09:14:26.825 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
11-26 09:14:26.844 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
11-26 09:14:26.855 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
11-26 09:14:26.887 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
11-26 09:14:26.887 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskWriteViolation
11-26 09:14:26.889 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
11-26 09:14:26.935 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
11-26 09:14:26.937 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology I/c: Token loaded from file. Expires in: 344773986 ms.
11-26 09:14:26.937 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology I/c: Scheduling next attempt in 344473 seconds.
11-26 09:14:27.014 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskWriteViolation
11-26 09:14:27.014 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskWriteViolation
11-26 09:14:27.037 30654-30706/tech.trilobite.geology D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
11-26 09:14:27.130 30654-30732/tech.trilobite.geology W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
11-26 09:14:27.130 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
11-26 09:14:27.131 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskWriteViolation
11-26 09:14:27.302 30654-30735/tech.trilobite.geology I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 74df444, I409c65498b
                                                                Build Date                       : 06/22/16
                                                                OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.08.00.02
                                                                Local Branch                     : N16
                                                                Remote Branch                    : 
                                                                Remote Branch                    : 
                                                                Reconstruct Branch               : 
11-26 09:14:27.315 30654-30735/tech.trilobite.geology I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-26 09:14:27.315 30654-30735/tech.trilobite.geology D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
11-26 09:14:27.599 30654-30750/tech.trilobite.geology W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
11-26 09:14:27.895 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskReadViolation
11-26 09:14:27.897 30654-30654/tech.trilobite.geology W/f: Suppressed StrictMode policy violation: StrictModeDiskWriteViolation
11-26 09:14:29.151 30654-30733/tech.trilobite.geology W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
11-26 09:14:29.160 30654-30733/tech.trilobite.geology I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:2
11-26 09:14:29.160 30654-30733/tech.trilobite.geology I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 2
```

Comment: You should include the layout that doesn't work in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a ConstraintLayout issue. You aren't using any constraints!

ConstraintLayout uses constraints to let views position themselves relative to each other and can also use them to define the dimensions of a view.

The correct equivalent to `match_parent` for a View in a ConstraintLayout is to to set the height and/or width to 0dp (sometimes referred to as "match constraints") then make sure the View has appropriate constraints set on it. In your case:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    tools:context="tech.trilobite.geology.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:context="tech.trilobite.geology.MainActivity"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here the height and width of the fragment are set to 0dp, meaning it looks to its constraints to determine its size. The constraints hook all four sides of the Fragment to the edges of its parent so it will expand to fill that space.

What was likely happening before was that the Fragment was working, but you just couldn't see it because it had zero size.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thanks, Lewis.  It is all good now - the Google map now appears on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a optimization issue with gradle, you should try disabling instant run and disable this:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I am brand new to Android development, though.
Which part of the build.gradle file should I add this to?  I tried putting it under DefaultConfig but the system came up with an error.

Comment: Thanks.  Changed build.gradle, rebuilt and ran, but same log messages, and same result - white screen.

Comment: I'd suggest not using ConstraintLayout, I had so much issue recently related to it... It's still pretty new and contains lots of bug